# How to get instance of ItemsPanel?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing custom control where I switch default `ItemsPanel` with

```
ItemsPanelProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGrid),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ItemsPanelTemplate(
    new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(AdvancedVirtualizingStackPanel)))));
```

How can I get reference to the instance of created `AdvancedVirtualizingStackPanel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will answer myself.

First you need to get `ItemsPresenter`. You can use this code:

```
ItemsPresenter itemsPresenter = 
    (ItemsPresenter)GetTemplateChild(ItemsPresenterTemplateName);
// You have to name ItemsPresenter (using value of 
// ItemsPresenterTemplateName string) in your XAML
```

Then:

```
itemsPresenter.ApplyTemplate(); // In case template is not applied yet
_stackPanel = 
    Helper.GetVisualChild<AdvancedVirtualizingStackPanel>(itemsPresenter);
```

And you got your panel. 
Code for `Helper.GetVisualChild()`:

```
public static T GetVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : Visual
{
    T child = default(T);

    int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
    {
        Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        child = v as T;
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
        }
        if (child != null)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return child;
}
```